# Bitmap(imageview) does not scale properly ,to fit exactly to linearlayout

Tags: bitmap, android-linearlayout

i want to scale the bitmap , to fit exactly to the linear layout

i have one Linearlayout

```
 <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/lin_layout1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                        android:paddingRight="10dip"
                        android:paddingTop="20dip" >

                        <!-- <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/image1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                            android:layout_weight="0.66" 
                            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
                            android:src="@drawable/abc"
                           /> -->                           
                    </LinearLayout>
```

i have defined one imageview dynamically as follows,

```
Imageview img = new ImageView(myclass);

                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams vp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1);
                    vp.setMargins(2, 20, 2, 20);
                    vp.gravity=Gravity.BOTTOM;          
                    img.setLayoutParams(vp);
                    img.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
```

i have generated scaled-bitmap from database

i have decoded it as follows

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromDatabase(byte[] bs,
            int length, Options options2,int reqwidth,int reqheight) 
    {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

        BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bs, 0, length, options2); 

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options2, reqwidth, reqheight);
        Log.d("In sample size", ""+options.inSampleSize);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        Bitmap bmap= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bs, 0, length, options);

        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmap, 130, reqheight, false);

    }

    public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) 
    {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
            if (width > height) {
                inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);
            } else {
                inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);
            }
        }
        return inSampleSize;
    }
```

and finally generated bitmap set to imageview

```
img.setImageBitmap(bmnew);
img.setOnClickListener(smile_reader);
img.setOnLongClickListener(smile_reader);
l1.addView(img);//Added imageview to linearlayout
```

but it does not scale properly ,

imageview height does bot match with linearlayout height.

imageview looks smaller than required, i don't know where i am missing 
so any help is appriciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hello vijay, I am also having the same problem. Did you got any solution on this..?

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like below...

-calculate max possible size using

```
options.inSampleSize = Math.max(inWidth/dstWidth, inHeight/dstHeight);  //still it will return image larger than your targeted size
```

-Load the image using

```
Bitmap roughBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);
```

-finally resize to desired dimensions using

```
Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(roughBitmap, (int) (roughBitmap.getWidth() * values[0]), (int) (roughBitmap.getHeight() * values[4]), true);
```